# Solve the equation a * b = c, where a, b and c are natural numbers

Tags: haskell, equation, brute-force

I have some natural number `c`. I want to find all pairs of natural numbers `a and b`, where `a < b`, such as `a * b = c`.

I have a solution:

```
solve c = do solveHelper [1..c] c where
                   solveHelper xs c = do
                       x <- xs
                       (division, modulo ) <- return (c `divMod` x)
                       True <- return (modulo  == 0)
                       True <- return (x <= division)
                       return (x, division)
```

Example:

```
*Main> solve 10
[(1,10),(2,5)]
```

Is there a way to accelerate my code, or a better algorithm I should use?

Comment: I imagine it's faster to find the prime factors of `c`, then find all the ways of grouping them into two groups.

Comment: λ let f c = [(a,b) | a <- [1..c], b <- [1..c], a<b, a*b==c]

Comment: @Shanthakumar you can avoid creating a bunch of `b` values that would be filtered out: `let f c = [(a, b) | a <- [1 .. c], b <- [1 .. a - 1], a * b == c]`.

Comment: oh yeah xD `let f c = [(a, b) | b <- [1 .. c], a <- [1 .. b - 1], a * b == c]`

Comment: @Shanthakumar Once `b` is chosen, there is only one possible value for `a` that can satisfy `a*b==c`, that is `div c b`. I'd check that single value rather than all the values in `[1..b-1]`.

Comment: @chi, it is clever idea, but It is slow too.

Comment: You should consider using the approach @chi described, but instead of using `div`, use `quotRem`. This will let you check the result really quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's one optimization you don't use: you don't have to try every value from `0` to `c`.

`a < b` and `a * b = c`, so `a * a < c`, meaning you only have to try numbers from `0` to `sqrt c`. Or, if you don't want to compute the square root of `c`, you can stop as soon as `a * a >= c`.

To do so, you can replace `[1..c]` by `(takeWhile (\x -> x * x < c) [1..])`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do much, much better. The basic idea is this: first, factorize the number; then enumerate the partitions of the factorization. The product of each partition is a solution. There are fast factorization algorithms out there, but even the naive one is quite an improvement on your code; so:

```
factorize :: Integer -> [Integer]
factorize n
    | n < 1 = error "no. =("
    | otherwise = go 2 n
    where
    go p n | p * p > n = [n]
    go p n = case quotRem n p of
        (q, 0) -> p:go p q
        _      -> go (p+1) n
```

I will use the very nice [multiset-comb](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-comb-0.2.3/docs/Math-Combinatorics-Multiset.html) package to compute partitions of the set of factors. It doesn't support the usual `Foldable`/`Traversable` stuff out of the box, so we have to roll our own `product` operation -- but in fact this can be a bit more efficient than using the `product` that the standard interface would give us anyway.

```
import Math.Combinatorics.Multiset

productMS :: Multiset Integer -> Integer
productMS (MS cs) = product [n^p | (n, p) <- cs]

divisors :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
divisors n =
    [ (a, b)
    | (aMS, bMS) <- splits (fromList (factorize n))
    , let a = productMS aMS; b = productMS bMS
    , a <= b
    ]
```

For unfair timings, we can compare in ghci:

```
*Main> :set +s
*Main> length $ solve (product [1..10])
135
(3.55 secs, 2,884,836,952 bytes)
*Main> length $ divisors (product [1..10])
135
(0.00 secs, 4,612,104 bytes)
*Main> length $ solve (product [1..15])
^CInterrupted. [after several minutes, I gave up]
*Main> length $ divisors (product [1..15])
2016
(0.03 secs, 33,823,168 bytes)
```

Here `solve` is your solution, `divisors` is mine. For a fair comparison, we should compile; I used this program:

```
main = print . last . solve . product $ [1..11]
```

(And similar with `divisors` in place of `solve`.) I compiled with `-O2`; yours used 1.367s total, mine 0.002s total.